# Oracle JET - Creating chart with JSON-data

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, oracle-jet

I'm trying to populate a pie chart with some JSON-data. My datasource is restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all. I retrieve the data with a $.getJSON and I create a temporary array which in turn is used as a datasource. I then bind the source to the pie chart. That what I think I'm doing atleast..

The error I'm getting is following

> my-piechart-viewModel.js:25 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: data is not 
>       defined
>       at new myPieChartModel (my-piechart-viewModel.js:25)
>       at Object.CreateComponent (ojcomposite.js:1808)
>       at ojcustomelement.js:385

My code looks like this

HTML

```
<oj-chart id="pieChart1" aria-label= 'TestPieChart'
          type="pie"
          series='[[datasource]]'
          style="max-width:500px;width:100%;height:350px;">
</oj-chart>
```

JS

```
function myPieChartModel() {
            var self = this;        
            self.data = ko.observableArray();
            $.getJSON("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").
                then(function(countries) {
                    var tempArray = [];
                    $.each(countries, function() {
                        tempArray.push({
                            name: this.name, 
                            population: this.population
                        });
                    });
                    self.data(tempArray);
            });
            self.datasource = ko.observableArray(data);
        }
    return myPieChartModel;
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm very new to Oracle's JET, and I have very little experience with JSON overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you defined something as `self.data` you cannot later access it by calling just `data`. So you need to change your last line to:

`self.datasource = ko.observableArray(self.data);`

2. Even if you do do that, you'll get this error:

> The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined.

That is, you cannot pass an observableArray into an observableArray. `self.data` should just be a normal JS array.

`self.data = [];`

But a normal JS array does not fire any events when its values are changed, so you'll need to update the observableArray `datasource` again. Your full code can be like this:

```
function myPieChartModel() {
        var self = this;        
        self.data = [];
        self.datasource = ko.observableArray(self.data);
        $.getJSON("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").
            then(function(countries) {
                $.each(countries, function() {
                    self.data.push({
                        name: this.name, 
                        population: this.population
                    });
                });
                self.datasource(self.data);
        });
    }
return myPieChartModel;
```

---

Let me know if it works. I have a feeling that your JSON data will also need to be modified like this:

```
self.data.push({name: this.name, 
                items: [this.population]
               });
```

Why? Because that's how Oracle JET expects it. Here's the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=pieChart&demo=default).

Comment: Ok, the component is loading now - saying 'No data to display' so that's progress. I get a warning this time in the console saying: - "


>jQuery.Deferred exception: data is not defined ReferenceError: data is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/js/jet-composites/my-piechart/my-piechart-viewModel.js:23:37)
    at mightThrow (http://localhost:8000/js/libs/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js:3534:29)
    at process (http://localhost:8000/js/libs/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.js:3602:12) undefined " -

So somethings missing.. How do I determine what's wrong from the error?

Comment: Oh damn, my bad. I gave a lecture about using 'self' and I myself forgot it. Try my code now.
To answer your question: The error says data is not defined. So have a look through the code and see what's wrong with `data` variable.

Comment: I feel stupid, but could it be that the JSON-data is not suitable for charts? Or the data I'm calling?

Comment: Well the structure of the JSON data is not correct for the chart. That's why I told you to try the last part, where I put population inside 'items'.

OJET can handle the data only in one format, which you can see in the documentation I mentioned. In fact that link is enough to solve nearly all your OJET problems.

Comment: If you are thinking that you need to look for some other sample data besides the countries JSON, that's not required. We can't expect all JSONs in the world to be in OJET format or vice versa. We'll simply have to manipulate the data to meet our requirements, like I showed above.

Comment: Browsing through the documentation I find no answers to why the data isn't being loaded. Having tried out your suggested modification of the data the result is the same as before - the chartmodel expresses 'No data to display' - hence why I asked wether the JSON-data mattered or not. Got any other ideas as to why it isn't loading the specified data?

Comment: I am embarrased.. and THANK YOU for the help. I missed one small, but very important, detail. I had forgotten the "self" in the datasource..

Comment: No worries, nothing to be embarrassed about :) That's what this site is for, to help each other out. Glad it worked it finally